# Flux.buffer() doesnt work with switchIfEmpty

Tags: java, spring, rest, project-reactor, flux

I have a scenario in which I will get a list of entities from `DB` using

```
repository.getAllByIds(ids)
```

which will return `Flux<Entity>`

in case of the Flux is empty then i need to call `handleAllEntitiesNotFound()` else i need to call `handleNotFoundEntities()`

```
repository.getAllByIds(ids)
                .buffer()
                .switchIfEmpty(__ -> handleAllEntitiesNotFound(ids, erroneousEntities))
                .flatMap(list -> handleNotFoundEntities(list))


private Flux<Entity> handleAllEntitiesNotFound(List<String> ids, List<ResponseError> erroneousEntities) {
    Flux.fromIterable(ids).subscribe(id -> erroneousEntities.add(new ResponseError("Not Found", "Not Found", id)));
    return Flux.empty();
}
```

I'm using `buffer()` to collect the list into `Flux<List<Entity>>`

The problem is, when i call the service, it halts, no response no logs no anything, if i removed the line                     `.switchIfEmpty(__ -> handleAllEntitiesNotFound(ids, erroneousEntities))` it works and return a response but without handling the `handleAllEntitiesNotFound`

What could be the problem using `buffer()` with `switchIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've come to the wrong conclusion here - `buffer()` and `switchIfEmpty()` work without a problem together:

```
Flux.empty()
        .buffer()
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(List.of(1)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println); //Prints "[1]"
```

However, your `handleAllEntitiesNotFound()` method is very suspicious. You seem to be passing in an existing list, creating a new `Flux` to add to it, and then returning an empty Flux. The example isn't runnable so it's impossible to narrow down the *exact* cause, but there's a few points that could well be the culprit (either individually or in tandem):

- Mutating an existing object that's passed into a reactive stream is generally considered bad form. It's much easier and safer to return a *new* list (and you can merge that list with another if you want when the reactive stream completes.)
- You're creating a `Flux` simply to read from one list, and add elements into another. That's confusing, and makes very little sense. Just use standard Java streams (i.e. `ids.stream().map(id -> new ResponseError("Not Found", "Not Found", id)).collect(Collectors.toList())`.)
- You're returning `Flux.empty()`, which is almost certainly why there's no response. One would usually expect `switchIfEmpty()` to return a non-empty Flux, unless you're deliberately just using it as a side-effect.
- `handleNotFoundEntities` seems like a strange choice of name for a method which would seem to be passed the entities that *were* found.